# Pass data from array to function vue

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, chart.js

i'm having troubles with passing data to the function myChart, in the mounted part. I'm new in vuejs and having some difficulties in understanding whats wrong.
i want to pass data in labels and datasets, which are called from mine function. Anyone can help? Thanks in advance
the code:

```
<script>
import Chart from 'chart.js';
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                tests:[]
            };
        },
        created(){
            this.mine();

        },
          methods: {
            mine(){
                let self = this;
                this.$http.get('tests/mine').then(response=>{
                    self.tests = response.data.tests;
                }).then(error=>{
                    console.log(error) ;
                });
            }},
            mounted() {
            var self=this;
            var ctx = document.getElementById("weightchart");
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: test.dt_test,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'weight',
                        data: test.weight,
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
                            'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
                            'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
                            'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
                            'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
                            'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)'
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero:true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
            },

        computed: {},
        watch: {}


    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating another function for asynchronous call you could add get call inside mounted and in its return in .then() function create your chart and perform other operations.

Other way could be you return promise object from the method and then on its .done() method you could write your mounted code logic.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. What is happening here your code is finished executing before you get the data from the server. When you are calling the methods mine(), it is sending HTTP request asynchronously. But your Vue code does't wait for the response it will get. Instead it continues running the rest of the script. By the time you get the response from the server, Vue already initialized your chart with the blank data.

So you have to make sure you initialize your chart after you successfully get the data from the server. Put the initialization code within a method and call that method after you get the data from the server --

```
            this.$http.get('tests/mine').then(response=>{
                self.tests = response.data.tests;
                // initialize your chart here, like -
                // this.initChart();
            }.bind(this)).then(error=>{
                console.log(error) ;
            });
```

Comment: thanks for helping :) i did as u said and still no data shown, only empty chart. i think i might be calling them the wrong way or sth, because mine() work great.    this.$http.get('tests/mine').then(response=>{
                    self.tests = response.data.tests;
                    self.chartinit();

                }).then(error=>{
                    console.log(error) ;
                });
            },
            chartinit() {
            var self=this;
            var ctx = document.getEleme

Comment: Create a method initChart() and then move all the code from mounted to that method. After than call the method initChart() after you get the data. See the line in my answer, I have commented that line this.initChart(). :-)

Comment: yeah, that's what i did but nothing changed.

Comment: Can you post your code on jsbin and share the link??